What safety precautions are taken on dive trips to Elphistone?
I plan on diving Elphistone or one of the other famous reefs in the red sea, but I am worried about sharks, especially since I read that October to March encountering an oceanig white tip is high.
I am trying to find out what dive operations are commonly doing in terms of measures and briefing.
So far I read the following:

Groups don't float on the water, they try to enter and go down and exit as fast as possible.
Diving happens in big groups of 20 people
Groups are supposed to stay together, but from what I see people don't even stay with their buddy
When a shark gets very close you should turn your back to it, so you are protectd by the tank
Contradicting to the last point - you should never turn your back to the shark

I read some diving shop sites from the area, but none have detailed information on these questions, such as what is even the likelyhood to see these sharks and what the protocol is.

Diving can be a wonderful experience. It's not without risk but quite safe if managed properly. The major risks of diving are not related to sharks or any type of wildlife but the process of diving itself: problems with equipment, not following proper procedure for descending or ascending, running out of air, health/fitness issues, doing something stupid, etc.
If you want to have a safe an enjoyable experience, then these are the things you should be focusing on the most. The good news is they are almost entirely under your control and straight forward to take care of.
Sharks come rarely into play for diving incidents. The total number of fatalities ever attributed to oceanic white tip shark is 3, which is not zero but it's a really really small number compared to the millions of dives that people do every year.
Shark encounters can be great! On my last snorkeling/diving in the Maldives we encountered  white tip and black tip reef sharks every single time and sometimes dozens of them. Granted, the reef sharks are smaller than the oceanic ones, but the same basic principle applies: if you don't bother the fish, the fish won't bother you.
In the EXTREMELY rare case of having to deal with an unusually aggressive shark:

Alert your dive master and follow their instructions
Alert your dive master and follow their instructions
Alert your dive master and follow their instructions
In the very rare case that your dive master is asleep at the wheel: DON"T PANIC
Face the shark, look at them, do not turn your back, do not try to swim away
If the shark approaches with in arm lengths reach out an push their head firmly down

Please don't let the fear of sharks get in the way of having a wonderful diving experience. The chances of seeing a real shark are quite small (unless you actively look) and the chances of being hurt by one are WAY lower than having a car accident on the ride to the beach. Many divers are actually excited of being able to see a shark in the wild! That's not everyone's cup of tea, but if you are diving with a reputable and skilled diving company you will be perfectly fine !
Edit based in the comment:
Given the excessive media hype it's perfectly understandable to be worried about shark attacks. However the actual risk is quite small. In 2023 there was only one shark related fatality  in Egypt and it was not related to diving.
I hope you can get comfortable with that idea. If you can't, its probably better if you don't dive. You will not enjoy yourself if you are constantly worried and looking over your shoulder. This would much more dangerous than any shark: the number one thing that kills divers is panic.

White tip reef sharks are completely different to oceanic white tip sharks, the most dangerous shark in the world, according to some. And there have been hundreds of documented fatal attacks, not just 3.

@user1721135 According to Wikipedia, while the oceanic whitetip may be responsible for "potentially hundreds" of deaths of people from ships attacked during WWII, "Subsequently, the species is recorded to have attacked 21 people between 1955 and 2020, including nine divers, eight swimmers, two fishermen, one shipwrecked person and one fallen pilot. Five of these attacks were fatal."

@TripeHound if you get eaten in the middle of the ocean chances are it was an oceanic white tip. Considering how rarely people spend time offshore, where there is a chance to meet them, the designation of most dangerous shark makes sense.

@user1721135 I got three from Forbes (https://www.forbes.com/sites/scotttravers/2024/06/12/a-biologist-spotlights-the-7-most-lethal-sharks-in-the-world/)  In 2023 Egypt had two unprovoked attacks including 1 fatality (https://www.floridamuseum.ufl.edu/shark-attacks/yearly-worldwide-summary/) . The fatality was NOT related to a dive. The vast majority of diving incidents is due to diving mistakes. As long as you dive with a certified Dive master, follow proper procedure and dive conservatively within your personal limits you will be safe.

And don't watch Jaws before the trip.

@Hilmar oceanic white tips are offshore, when they take ship wrecked people, there is not much proof left and normal people don't encounter them, because they live offshore. Going to elphistone almost guarantees to encounter them. So its skyrockets your risk. Many people make the argument that OWT are the most dangerous, even more so than great whites. Would you go dive with great whites? If not why, they aren't more dangerous per encounter compared to OWT.

@user1721135 - please give links to your claims. Hilmar and Tripehound have references. You do not, so it appears your claims are untrue.

Frankly, the OP provides a classic example of inappropriate risk management for outdoor activities - focusing on a high-consequence but very low probability potential outcome and losing sight of the many higher probability outcomes that could still be high consequence.

@RoryAlsop Forbs is hardly a source, but here: https://ocean.si.edu/ocean-life/sharks-rays/most-dangerous-all-sharks and https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/sinking-uss-indianapolis-triggered-worst-shark-attack-history-25715092/

@JonCuster where did I lose sight of higher probability risks? Trusting dive shops to brief your correctly is not good risk management.

I agree 100% with Hilmar, diving is dangerous and that has nothing to do with the fish which includes sharks.  A more common injury with diving and wild life would be touching fire coral.
That being said some dive operations feed the sharks.  This is asking for trouble as the sharks associate human divers and food.  Here is a video of such.  The feeder wears chain mail with the divers near by.  In this video they form a circle on the ocean floor.
What happens if one of the observers experiences an equipment failure?  They'll have to navigate through the shark frenzy to go to the surface.
Very stupid in my opinion.
For the record the video shown is from the Bahamas.

Touching fire coral may be more common but its not critical and its easily mitigated by wearing gloves or simply not touching anything.

@user1721135 True, but it is also 100% within a diver's control.  Yet they still do it.  "Don't touch the coral" is one of the first and most often repeated lessons.
